# Error en la generación de label JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al generar el ultimo label de mi tablero de ajedrez ya que lo imprime del tamaño completo de mi panel pero no se a que se deba este error.

La otra problemática que tengo es que en las primeras dos filas de mi tablero me pone los colores exactamente iguales pero en el resto respeta el orden que le di de acuerdo a mis condicionales.

**EJEMPLO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO**

```
package otraprueba;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class OtraPrueba extends JFrame {

    JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[8];
    JLabel tablero[][] = new JLabel[8][8];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);
    int yPosition = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtraPrueba op = new OtraPrueba();
        op.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        op.setVisible(true);
        op.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public OtraPrueba() {
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            label[i].setBounds(25 + (50 * i), 25, 30, 30);
            label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
            label[i].setForeground(Color.red);
            label[i].setBorder(border);
            label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label[i].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
                    myDraggingMethod(evt);//reemplaza a los metodos j1 j2 .... j8MouseDragged
                }
            });
            jpanel.add(label[i], null);
        }

        //        Inicializa el panel.
        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new JLabel();
                tablero[i][j].setBounds(25 + (50 * j), 25 + yPosition, 30, 30);
                tablero[i][j].setBorder(border);
                tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);

                if ((i % 2 == 0) == (j % 2 == 0)) {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }

                tablero[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                tablero[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                jpanel.add(tablero[i][j], null);
            }
            yPosition = 50 * i;
        }
    }

    public void myDraggingMethod(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) evt.getSource()).setLocation(newPosition(evt)[0], newPosition(evt)[1]);
        }
    }

    public int[] newPosition(MouseEvent evt) {
        int newX, newY;
        if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newX = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newX = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newX = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newX = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newX = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newX = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newX = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newX = 375;
        } else {
            newX = 375;
        }

        if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newY = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newY = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newY = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newY = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newY = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newY = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newY = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newY = 375;
        } else {
            newY = 375;
        }

        int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

        return retorno;
    }

}
```